# How to pass binary of an image to JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, base64

```
var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
context.drawImage( video, 0, 0 );
image.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
var image= dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
console.log(image);

var params = {
  // Request parameters
  "returnFaceId": "true",
  "returnFaceLandmarks": "false",
  "returnFaceAttributes": "age",
};

$.ajax({
  url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?" + $.param(params),
  beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
    // Request headers
    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","8b99a9ed839a40a08aa8b529ef0f9b8c");
  },
  type: "POST",
  // Request body
  data: [image],
})
```

Here is the code of the Javascript I capture the image and then pass it to the JSON object but this request is always show responce of **400** and here is the link of microsoft API

https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236

and here it is screenshot of API documentation.

Give me a hint how to pass image.

---

[image]

---

Comment: Export the image as a blob instead of base64 and use xmlhttprequest and FormData

Comment: yeah i tried it i pass image to bolb and it pass me a object of bolb then how to pass that object of bolb@Musa

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Ok so i spent some time fiddling with this and essentially the reason your example failed is because you were sending base64 data where as the api requires binary data. The issue then becomes converting an image to a blob. I've created a jsfiddle for the code below that correctly creates this binary blob from a canvas, which is loaded with a image randomly fetched from a url. It successfully receives a 200 response from the api. Take a look and let me know if you have any questions:

**https://jsfiddle.net/mq70h6pf/14/**

```
function getImageBlob(url, callback) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
    image.src = url;
    image.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
        canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        canvas.toBlob(callback);
    };
}

var randomImageUrl = "https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random";
getImageBlob(randomImageUrl, function(imageBlob) {
    $("#displayImage").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob)); //Check to see if blob can be correctly displayed, for reference only
    console.log(imageBlob);
    var params = {
      // Request parameters
      "returnFaceId": "true",
      "returnFaceLandmarks": "false",
      "returnFaceAttributes": "age",
    };
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?" + $.param(params),
      beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
        // Request headers
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","8b99a9ed839a40a08aa8b529ef0f9b8c");
      },
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/octet-stream",
      // Request body
      data: imageBlob,
      processData: false
    })
});
```